# Is there an API to get the balance per day for an account?

Tags: api, address, balance, solscan

I'm looking a way to get the account tranfers for an specific day.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

there is not really an API but you can build one yourself pretty easily and for free.

If you look at the chart in https://faucet.solana.com/monitor, you can see that there are daily points for the Solana accounts balance that we track.

This is how it's done behind the scenes: https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-devnet-faucet/blob/main/pages/api/monitorfaucet.ts

Basically you have an API endpoint that fetches the balance and stores it into a database, which can be hosted on the Vercel free tier.

Then, just run a Vercel cron job or a free Uptimerobot trigger onto that API route once a day.

Let me know if you have any questions regarding that.

If you are looking to fetch the actual transaction signatures that have happened during a certain time interval, use the getSignaturesForAddress RPC method, by specifying a before and an until timestamp that fits that day.
Here's the documentation for that RPC method: https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/getSignaturesForAddress